# Google GKE startup script not workin for GKE Node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am adding a startup script to my GKE nodes using terraform

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
  credentials = "google-key.json"
}


terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "tf-state-bucket-devenv"
    prefix = "terraform"
    credentials = "google-key.json"
   }
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = var.kube-clustername
  location = var.zone
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_preemptible_nodes" {
  name       = var.kube-poolname
  location   = var.zone
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = var.kube-nodecount

  node_config {
    preemptible  = var.kube-preemptible
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
    disk_size_gb = 10
    disk_type = "pd-standard"


    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true",
      startup_script = "cd /mnt/stateful_partition/home && echo hi > test.txt"
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]
  }
}
```

When i go into the GCP interface, select the node and view the metadata I can see the key/value is there

```
metadata_startup_script 
#!/bin/bash sudo su && cd /mnt/stateful_partition/home && echo hi > test.txt
```

However when running the below command on the node -

sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup -
-debug

I got the below -

```
startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
startup-script: INFO No startup scripts found in metadata.
startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

Does anyone know why this script is not working/showing up? - Is it because its a GKE node and google dont let you edit these, I cant actually find anything on their documentation where they specifically say that.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot specify startup scripts to run on GKE nodes. The node has a built-in startup sequence to initialize the node and join it to the cluster and to ensure that this works properly (e.g. to ensure that when you ask for 100 nodes you get 100 functional nodes) you cannot add additional logic to the startup sequence.

As an alternative, you can create a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) that runs on all of your nodes to perform node-level initialization. One advantage of this is that you can tweak your DaemonSet and re-apply it to existing nodes (without having to recreate them) if you want to change how they are configured.

Comment: Im essentially trying to do this https://medium.com/google-cloud/stateful-services-on-preemptible-nodes-with-google-kubernetes-engine-c73ac10b8253      I  need to copy of the kube config onto the nodes so they can drain the nodes.   Thats the problem.   I did try to follow this guide, but it didnt work, managed instance groups dont join the kubernetes cluster and if you change the instance template for your node pool, it breaks your whole setup.   but I think the theory is there.

Comment: I don't see a way to catch the shutdown signal without a shutdown script (which GKE doesn't allow you to set). So you may be out of luck unless / until this capability gets built into GKE itself. If you have a support contact at Google, I'd recommend raising a feature request with them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this metadata key name `metadata_startup_script` by this one `startup_script`.

In addition, your startup script runs as root user. you don't need to perform a `sudo su`

Comment: Hey, still same issue, says No startup scripts found in metadata.  - ive updated the main question to show my new terraform

Comment: Seems you cant do startup-scripts.  the problem was the key should be startup-script not startup_script.  - get this - Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 400: Cluster.node_config.metadata.key cannot be the reserved key "startup-script"., badRequest

Comment: It make sense. Answer to you question with that, it can be useful for the others!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to apply startup scripts to GKE nodes is to use a project-level metadata startup script like below:

```
resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "startup-script" {
  project = var.project_id
  key     = "startup-script"
  value   = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Hello world!
  EOF
}
```